# need a solution for syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, vba

I need help with this piece of code I am getting a run time error of 3144 - Syntax error in UPDATE statement the code below is;

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE RenewalList SET PremiumSum = " & DSum("PremxIPT", "RenewalList", "PolicyNo = '" & !policyNo & "' AND Client_Name = '" & Replace(!Client_Name, "'", "''") & "'") & " WHERE PolicyID = " & !PolicyID)
```

Comment: Print out your generated sql query and run it in your dmbs directly. Then look for mistakes.

Comment: You should parameterize your query already

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: I believe at the `AND Client_Name` portion, the `AND` should be a comma, like so: `, Client_Name` as the third value that is being SET. Print the query as the first person mentioned, and you'll see that the query doesn't look quite right.